# model failing to converge in R (increasing number of evaluations)

Tags: r

I have a couple of technical question in R pertaining to warning and error messages when a model fails to converge.

I'm using Generalized linear mixed effects models for my data and the warnings I get have to do with increasing the number of evaluations in R. I have a large data set of 8208, 23 variables (ncol) and 435 rows.

The three messages I got are as follows.

1. `fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 4 > columns / coefficients’`

2.`In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv, :Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.151201 (tol = 0.001,component 7)`

3. `(function (fn, par, lower = rep.int(-Inf, n), upper = rep.int(Inf,:failure to converge in 10000 evaluations.`

The model I'm using is as follows.

```
m0.5 <- glmer(match ~ Listgp + st.context + st.length + age + gender + (1|Listener), data = PATdata2, family = "binomial")
```

However, I'm prompted to rescale my variables.

So, my 2 questions are.

1. What is the syntax in R to increase the number of evaluations?
2. How do I rescale variables in R?

I already tried `?lmerControl, getOption('mxOptions'), as.character` but I couldn't reset the parameters.

I read in an earlier post that I can increase the number of iterations by applying the following command, `glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000))` which I did but still I got this message.

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0061514 (tol = 0.001, component 8)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Shad

Comment: Can you share your data or at least `summary(PATdata2)`? You should find out why the model matrix is rank deficient.

Comment: It looks like your model is too complex for the data. We need `str(PATdata2)` and `summary(m0.5)`

Comment: Thanks Roland and Thierry. I was able to resolve the issue by simplifying the original data set.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve the issue by simplifying the original data set, removing any blank values and increasing the number of observations.

```r
glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 10000))
```

Hope this can help others as well.